# I need a query to do something specific

Tags: mysql, sql, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

i have this situation:

**TABLE ONE:**

| Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1222 |

**TABLE TWO:**

| Code | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | bla bla |
| 2 | yadda yadda |

i need to put the quantity column in the table 2, using "CODE" as key… Anyone who could help me with this query? I'm using LibreOffice

**RESULT EXPECTED**

| CODE | Data | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bla bla | 1000 |
| 2 | yadda yadda | 1222 |

Answer (score 2):

its a simple join :

```
select t1.code, t2.Data, t1.Quantity
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
   on t1.code = t2.code
```